# How do I create an express route that handles an HTTP GET request which sends an a href tag

Tags: javascript, ajax, hyperlink, get

How do I create an express route that handles an HTTP GET request which sends an a href tag containing a link to an email address? Given No DOCTYPE declaration, html, head, body, or other tags should be present.

Here's what I've tried and it doesn't work:

```
router.get('/contact.ajax', function(req, res, next) {
res.send(<a href="aaa@gmail.com">aaa@gmail.com</a>);
});
```

in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My AJAX Site</h1>
    <p><button id = "contactButton" onclick = "buttonClicked()">Contact</button></p>
    <div id = "mainDiv"></div>
<script>
function buttonClicked(){
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(this.readyState ==4 && this.status == 200){
  var mainDiv = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
  mainDiv.appendChild(xhttp.responseText);
}
};
xhttp.open("GET","/contact.ajax",true);
xhttp.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to send from express (or your serverside code) is the email in a string.

```js
res.send('aaa@gmail.com')
```

Then when you get the string on the client side you can inject it into a tag.

```js
let mainDiv = document.getElementById('mainDiv')

mainDiv.innerHTML = `<a href="${responseText}">${responseText}</a>`
```

Note this is a simplified version.